# MySQL: SELECT with AND OR producing incorrect data?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table that is recording all the scoring plays for a sports application I am developing. I am trying to find out from the scoring table, how many assists a player has. There is a primary assist and a secondary assist, so I am trying to return the value of the total assists using a `COUNT(*) WHERE...`

I am using the following SQL statement:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teamassist13.AllScoringPlays WHERE GameId = 6124 AND SeasonId = 1 AND P_AssistId =  21 OR S_AssistId = 21;`

Which gives me the accurate scoring for game 6124 (it returns that the user has 2 assists), but when I switch `GameId` to 6125, it then shows the user has 1 assist, when they should have 0.

I have also tried the following statement:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AllScoringPlays WHERE GameId = 6124 AND SeasonId = 1 AND (P_AssistId =  21 OR S_AssistId = 21);`

Which then tells me the player has 1 assist for `GameId` 6124 (inaccurate, should be 2), and 0 assists for `GameId` 6125 (accurate).

```
`GameId` 6125 should return 0 assists
`GameId` 6124 should return 2 assists
```

This is the structure of the View I am currently querying:

```
| GameId | TeamId | SeasonId | LeagueId | GoalId | P_AssistId | S_AssistId |
   6124      1         1           1        20        21             23
   6124      1         1           1        19        20             21
```

It seems to be bypassing the OR statement, I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The query with the parentheses is correct.

Comment: The query with parenthesis is correct. I don't see how the query not working. I try it in the fiddle and the query is working as intended. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1aea3/5

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, it's been a long day, I must have been overlooking something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query is correct:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AllScoringPlays WHERE GameId = 6124 AND SeasonId = 1 AND
(P_AssistId = 21 OR S_AssistId = 21);
```